# Exactly what IS a folder in TFVC?

Tags: tfs, tfvc

I'm trying to wrap my head around the TFS folder concept. I've found a lot of explanations of how to create them, how to convert them to branches, how to move folders around, etc. etc. but absolutely nothing that explains *what a folder is*. When would I choose a branch over a folder? What are the advantages/disadvantages of one over the other?

Any references or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A folder is just an arbitrary hierarchal organization method. It's no different than your file system. A branch is a type of folder with special properties to support concurrent development.

Comment: OK, thanks. I get the idea of a folder. I get the idea of a branch. What I don't get is how a branch is a type of folder. The two concepts are just refusing to meld together in my brain :)

Maybe I'm thinking too literally of file-system folders?

Comment: Think of a tree. You have a trunk, then branches sprout off of the trunk. You specify a folder as a "trunk" (this is usually a top-level folder called Main or something similar). Then you branch, which creates a copy of that folder  and includes all sorts of metadata to establish a hierarchy of branches. The internal representation is smart enough to not be duplicating all of this stuff even if it looks like a direct copy to you, which is where a branch differs from a straight up copy.